# d3.csv reading two combined csvs as response from servlet

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3.csv(url, function(data)}) to get some data from server. What if I want to do two separate plots with two different data sets. If I combine those two CSVs and return them as response text of URL.  So essentially hitting URL returns two combined CSVs. If I put some special characters at the end of one, how can I really separate these two CSVs in javascript.

I tried doing data.split() .. which of course gives error as data is object here. 
I tried using d3.csv.parse .. that does not seem to work either.

Comment: If the two CSVs have different column names, you could just add the columns of the second to the first. Otherwise, you should be able to simply concatenate the files (minus header). If neither is possible, you can also send two requests, one for each file.